# Java Instrumentation

Tags: java

Я создал jar файл для java агента для того чтобы использовать его в своем приложении , java агент подсчитывает размер объекта  с помощью класса Instrumentation. В эклипсе я добавил параметр виртуальной машины : -javaagent: D:\ObjectSizeFetcher.jar , когда я запустил класс для проверки работы java agent , он выдал такую ошибку:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

класс который подсчитывает размер объектов:

```
package ob;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

class ObjectSizeFetcher {
private static Instrumentation instrumentation;
public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
instrumentation = inst;
}
public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
}
}
```

класс для тестирования ObjectSizeFetcher:

```
package ob;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class main {
public static void main(String [] args) {
ObjectSizeFetcher obj = new ObjectSizeFetcher();

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    arr.add("a");

}

System.out.println(ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(arr));
} 
}
```

манифест файл :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
PreMain-Class: ob.ObjectSizeFetcher
```

Comment: А класс ObjectSizeFetcher  точно ни от чего не нужно наследовать? Да и статические методы настораживают.